# MEE6 - Can I manually grant a level up to a user?

Tags: discord

On the ranking list I can see only the "reset xp" button. But is there a way I can increase the xp of a user to make it level-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a "give-xp" command which can fit in my need.